# TypeError: 'JavaPackage' object is not callable (sc._jvm)

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, py4j

I have below class written in Scala:

```
package com.ing.wbaa.spark.udf


class test() {

   def hello = println("hello")

   def addInt( a:Int, b:Int ) : Int = {
      var sum:Int = 0
      sum = a + b
      return sum
   }
}
object test{

   def main(argv: Array[String]): Unit = {

      val app = new test()

      app.hello;
      app.addInt(1,1)
   }
}
```

I am trying to access hello method in Jupyter notebook. To do that I created jar file of above class and did following:

```
pyspark --jars /home/path/of/jar/is/udf_2.12-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

when I run

```
sc._jvm.com.ing.wbaa.spark.udf.Test.main()
```

I get `TypeError: 'JavaPackage' object is not callable` and when I try to run

```
sc._jvm.com.ing.wbaa.spark.udf.Test.hello
```

I get `<py4j.java_gateway.JavaPackage object at 0x7fd86a95e850>`

Can please someone tell me how can I use `hello` or `addInt` method in jupyter notebook. Thank you

Also

```
sc._jvm.com.ing.wbaa.spark.udf.Test.hello()
```

gives `TypeError: 'JavaPackage' object is not callable` when it should have call hello function of test class.

Comment: Pyspark can define UDFs as well. Do you really need Scala? Also, test class is lowercase, so how is Pyspark importing it with uppercase? Does the Scala class on its own run without error?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

uninstall spark
uninstall pyspark
after that install pyspark 2.4.*

the problem is that the spark version probably 3.x doesn't supported by Java version
also ensure that you've java 8 in your path

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).